# How to create a pin on a lefleat map from geolocation?

Tags: javascript, html, api, leaflet

I have created a map using LeafleatJS and want to create a pin on my map to indicate where the user is. I've tried code below:

```
L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("Me").openPopup();
```

What is wrong with it? I have a Fiddle where I have created a map which centers the users location. Please see fiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/jackbillstrom/5RjB7/](http://jsfiddle.net/jackbillstrom/5RjB7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script-tag at the end of your body to:

```
var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 16});

var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 13, layers: [cloudmade]});


function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: true});
```